# Symfony private messages

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, private-messaging

I want to make private messages in my site. I want that user can delete  received or sent messages. For it I need two tables one for send message and one for receive....Is it to possible that when user send messages, it automatically add fro two tables? or it is better to make some relations with tables? or  maybe exist better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need just one table:

```
Message:
  columns:
    from: integer
    to: integer
    header:  string(100)
    body:    blob
    show_in_outcoming: 
      type: boolean
      default: true
    show_in_incoming: 
      type: boolean
      default: true
    is_read:  
      type: boolean
      default: false
  UserFrom:
    class: sfGuardUser
    local: from
    foreign: id
    foreignType: one
    type: one
  UserTo:
    class: sfGuardUser
    local: to
    foreign: id
    foreignType: one
    type: one
```

where

- **is_read** indicates whether or not the message been read (false - unread, true - read - for incoming messages only)

If the user who sends the message want to delete it, we simply hide it (not delete from the DB) - set show_in_outcoming to false.
If the user who received the message want to delete it, we hide it too - set show_in_incoming to false. This approach allows us to recover the "hidden" messages (or remove them altogether)

Comment: Thank you! What is type field?

Comment: Column **type** tells us whether an Message is a IncomingMessage or a OutgoingMessage. This column will be automatically added to CREATE TABLE `message` SQL query (if you are generating it) - `type VARCHAR(255)`. This is how column aggregation inheritance knows which model each record in the database belongs to.

[More info](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/inheritance/en#column-aggregation)

Comment: I do not very understand about Doctrine Table Inheritance(and I can not understand  how it works)I have one table but three models.I want to generate module for messages, I need generate one modules for messages table?I will have one record in my DB for one message,for one user it will be out coming,for other incoming...

Comment: I think, I understand you. I have changed my answer slightly.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I think that there need one more column,  is_readSender ,and  is_readRecipiend...?

Comment: No, you don't. Why you need a is_read field for the sender? All that he should know is whether the _recipient is read his message or not_. **is_read** field is responsible for this. Of course, you may want to add some additional fields like created_at, updated_at and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should create a message table, with tow relation to user table:

```
message:
  columns:
    user_emitter_id: ...
    user_reciever_id: ...
    body: ...
  relations:
    userEmitter:
      class: user
      local: user_emitter_id
      foreign: id
    userReciever:
      class: user
      local: user_reciever_id
      foreign: id
```

Comment: but when user  delete for example receive message, it also will deleted for user that sent this message.

Comment: do not delete the message... just set user_reciever_id or user_emitter to null.

Comment: hm, is it good, do not delete  message from  database? hm, I think I shall do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a symfony plugin that allows you to do this. Check [sfSocialPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSocialPlugin).

Comment: Thank you! I now, I use this plugin now, but it's not exactly what I need. Now I disabled everything except private messages there, but before sent message, you need sent "friend request" And you can not delete messages/ And there are some little conflict between sfDoctrineGuard and sfSocial...So I want to write my own simple pm )

Answer (score 0):

```
Message:
  columns:
    from: integer
    to: integer
    header:  string(100)
    body:    blob
    show_in_outcoming: 
      type: boolean
      default: true
    show_in_incoming: 
      type: boolean
      default: true
    is_read:  
      type: boolean
      default: false

  relations:
    UserFrom:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: from
      foreign: id
      foreignType: one
      type: one
    UserTo:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: to
      foreign: id
      foreignType: one
      type: one
```